# Pyspark with geoparquet support on azure

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, geopandas, azure-synapse

I am wondering if it is possible to natively write to geoparquet (v1 released) format on azure using synapse notebooks.
Regards

The particular combination of software enables reduction in imports or over coding done to achieve storing data in latest format.

Comment: What does this have to do with geopandas? If nothing, please remove the tag. If there is a connection please clarify by [edit]ing your question

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDelgado, the geopandas comes into picture as native spark parquet writer is often used, whereas geopandas geoparquet (update) writes to synapse container. Workarounds are to code ability to write to abfss on microsoft azure.

Answer (score 0):

I try to install Geopandas in azure synapse using geopandas, we can use Geoparquet but I got this error.

[image]

As per [Azure Synapse Analytics Blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/bg-p/AzureSynapseAnalyticsBlog)

[image]

It's better to raise [support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request#create-a-support-request) for this issue.

Comment: The setup requires manual pre installation of dependencies to overcome said issue.